# Blender 2.6: How to Merge the Pros of Meshes and Surfaces

Tags: 3d-meshes, blender

there are two interesting kinds of objects: Meshes and Surfaces. Each of them offers very cool features.

### Object Type Specific Features

#### Nice Features of Surfaces:

*(for example)*

- They're as scalable as vector graphics (*really nice!*)
- You can build winding things real simply.

#### Nice Features of Meshes:

*(for example)*

- You can build organic things really good using the Sculpt Mode and a graphic tablet.
- You can use some special things like Physics.

### My Question

There are things for which Surfaces are better and things for which Meshes are better. But how can I use *both* the best features of Surfaces and the best features of Meshes on *one* object *at once*?

*For example:* How can I use Physics (*like on Meshes*) *on* lossless scalable objects (*like Surfaces*)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've always just leaned on mesh modifiers. I find meshes easier to work with in just about every way. If I ever use a curve, it's probably as an animation guideline rather than as a static shape.

> Advantage of Curve - they are scalable as vector graphics.

You can smooth meshes out by applying a `Subsurf` modifier. With an appropriately low resolution base mesh, it would work similarly to a Surface, with the added advantage of not requiring square patches like NURBS. See [this subdivisionmodeling tutorial](http://www.blendernewbies.com/tools/subdivisionmodeling/subd_PRIMER/page2.html#about) for examples of how Subdivision surfaces behave like, but better than, NURBS surfaces.

> Advantage of Curve - you can build winding things really simply.

Create a mesh. Optionally duplicate it using an Array modifier (e.g. you make one stairstep, then Array it out into a bunch of stairs) Then use a `Screw`, `Curve`, `Lattice`, or `Deform` modifier to guide it along a curved path.